# Changing ImageView size

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have an image show up when the name of it (TextVIew) is clicked. I have the code set up to what I believe is the right thing  but the app force closes when I launch it. This is just a test code, so its not my actual app, but the idea is the same so can someone help me figure out why this is crashing?

java file:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            image.getLayoutParams().height=20;
        }
    });
}
```

xml file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="show image" />
```

Comment: *Post your stack trace.*

Comment: post your logcat please...

Comment: I don't know what these are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have this code (below) inside `onCreate()`

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Try it.

**Update:**

The code could look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image = null;
    TextView text = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (image.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text.setText("hide the image");
                } else {
                    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    text.setText("show the image");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

and layout is here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="show the image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Specifically, after you call `setContentView()`

Comment: So that fixed the crashing issue, thanks. Now I found out my TextView is not clickable. How can I make it more like a button, but remain a TextView?

Comment: @Restnom I will take a look in a moment.

Comment: @Restnom If I understand right, what you want to achieve is that your image is not visible at the beginning and after you click the `TextView` the image will show. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, thats pretty much what I want it to do.

Comment: So, although this gets the job done, having a lot of invisble images will create a lot of empty blanks which will make my app look ugly. That is why I was hoping I could use the size changing method so that when the image is not shown it takes tiny or no space, and when it is showing it will be enlarged. So thanks, but I kind of need to use to size changing method. My problem at this point is why my TextView is not clickable?

Comment: @Restnom First part is simple to solve - use `android:visibility="gone"` in the layout. And the second part is ok with my code - I have tried it and my `TextView` is clickable.

Comment: Okay so let me test it out.

Comment: @janzoner You are the man! Thank you for this. Now just one tiny thing. How do I set a way to hide the image? Should I just use the onCLick method for the image which will return its visibility to gone or do you have a better suggestion?
EDIT: I did as I said with setting the onclick method for the image and it worked just fine. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Restnom Ok, you are welcome :) Anyway, I updated the code and the layout. Take a look if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fill your elements in `onCreate`, not as a field, after setting the content view;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    ...
```

And try setting the size of the `ImageView` not directly from layoutparams but with `setHeight/setWidth` functions

Comment: I got that part, thanks. I just need to find out how to make my TextVIew clickable now.

Comment: And about the setHeight functions, how do I use it exactly? Because I when I type text.setHeight I get an error and that doesnt show up in the options when I start to type it out.